# Why doesn't the teleport between places function in Roblox Studio accept tables of strings?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am having issues with the teleportation feature between places seem to accept my tables. I need to have a group of players' names sent from the group leader to the server script which teleports them. I need the values of the player names to be sent, which works, then the teleport function won't accept the string values that are verified as players using the function at the top of the code. Any help is appreciated.

The error that it gives is "Must be passed an array of players"

````
local placeId = 5170420690
local partyPlayersList = {}

local function getPlayerFromName(name)
   for _, player in pairs(game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers()) do
      if player.Name:lower() == name:lower() then
          return player
      end
   end
end




game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage').TeleportSquad.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, player1id, player2id, player3id, player1name, player2name, player3name) -- Connects a function to execute when the "TeleportSquad" event is fired
    local leaderUserId = player1id
    local player = getPlayerFromName(player1name)
    if player2id ~= nil then
        local player2 = getPlayerFromName(player2name)
        local partyPlayersList = {
            (player),
            (player2)
        }
    elseif player3id ~= nil then
        local player2 = getPlayerFromName(player2name)
        local player3 = getPlayerFromName(player3name)
        local partyPlayersList = {
            (player),
            (player2),
            (player3)
        }
    else
        local partyPlayersList = {
            (player)
        }       

    end


      game:GetService('TeleportService'):TeleportPartyAsync(placeId, partyPlayersList)


end)```
````

Comment: try declaring `local partyPlayerList` before the `if`/`elseif`/`else`?

Comment: Hi @Dmitri , The party player list is called right at the top before anything else, thanks for your time though.

Comment: But when you use `local partyPlayerList = ` inside your `if`, etc. blocks, aren't you creating a new, separate one with more limited scope rather than modifying the existing one?  Try removing `local` from the statements inside the `if`/`elseif`/`else` blocks. (just for `partyPlayersList`)

Comment: Hi, I have removed the local part now and it is to little effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by using one of the values in the playergui to find the correct player, so far this only works for the one person but I am testing the features for adding players to your party so you can go as a team. 
Thankyou for your time and help,
*KFrog*

Comment: I am still unable to teleport all of the players as this is much more complicated and requires many scripts because I have to send a position of a value in the game explorer to the server to teleport. If anyone wants to help me with this, please Discord message me. KillerFrog11#6398 
Thanks in advance